Camp Team Automated Generator: Moving Data to Keep Columns at 10
I've been hitting a wall with my code. I am making an automation macro for excel for a ministry that does summer camps. At these camps girls and boys are split into teams based loosely on grade. For instance, the blue team (which is the youngest team of boys) can have boys grades K-1st on it. But it could be all kindergartenrs, or all first graders depending on info in the attached spreadsheet. I'm making this in excel because information entered in the one sheet is used for another ministry purpose (but isn't involved in the code).
I can get everyone into teams beautifully, but my director only wants teams to have a maximum of 10 kids. I can also get kids to move to the next team, but unfortunately we obviously can't have a 1st grader on a team of 5th graders. So when I move a kid to the next team, and that team is also full, the first kid in that team needs to be bumped over. But now I have to check again if that kid can even be bumped over, because if the next team for that kid is also full, then the next team has to have a kid bumped over a team! This has caused me quite the headache, and I'm even wondering if this will even automate anything.
So my question is: in vba for Excel, how do I move data over, making sure each column only has 10 nonheader pieces of info and how do I handle checking if a column is appropriate for data to be placed in it?
Sheet 1 is a list of campers and addresses(not posting obviously) starting in column A, dat goes: First Name, Last Name, Street, City, Zip, Grade, Gender
This macro is tied to a command button in sheet 1, and the teams list is generated in sheet 2
I'm thinking I need to loop some part of my code, I think it would be cleanest to have my code use recursion, but I could be wrong. Recursion with my CellToFill sub again worked beautifully, but it is getting tedious to track which kids need to be placed and which ones need to be bumped. I thought of using a stack implementation, but this ended up not working out. I could have implemented it wrong though.
Here is my CellToFill sub
Sub CellToFill(team As Integer, r As Integer, nArray() As Variant)
   


    Dim availableCell As Integer
    Dim nextTeam As Integer
    nextTeam = team + 1
    
    availableCell = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, team).End(xlUp).row + 1 'next avaialble cell in team column
    
    If availableCell = 14 Then 'team is at 10, move the child to next team
        availableCell = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, nextTeam).End(xlUp).row 'blank cell in next team
        If availableCell = 14 Then 'nextTeam is full, move one child from nextTeam over to another team
            End If
            Set curCell = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(4, nextTeam) 'first kid in team + 1
            availableCell = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, nextTeam + 1).End(xlUp).row 'find available cell in next team after team + 1
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(curCell.row, nextTeam).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(availableCell + 1, nextTeam + 1)
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(curCell.row, nextTeam).Delete Shift:=xlUp
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(availableCell + 1, nextTeam + 1)).PasteSpecial
            
            'Debug.Print curCell & " cell of child to move"
            'curCell.Value = " " & availableCell - 3 & ". " & nArray(r, 1) & " " & nArray(r, 2) & " - " & nArray(r, 8)
        Else
        Call CellToFill(team + 1, r, nArray) 'fill cell in next team
        End If    
   
    Else
    availableCell = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, team).End(xlUp).row + 1
    Set curCell = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(availableCell, team)
        curCell.Value = " " & availableCell - 3 & ". " & nArray(r, 1) & " " & nArray(r, 2) & " - " & nArray(r, 8) 'fill cell with info
    End If
    
End Sub


EDIT:
Here is sheet 1



First Name
Last name
Mailing
City
State
Zip
Gender
Grade




Michelle
Obama
1234 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12345
F
K


Mikaila
Peterson
1235 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12346
F
2


Tucker
Carlson
1236 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12347
M
3


Candace
Owens
1237 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12348
F
4


Janet
Parshell
1238 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12349
F
6


Shane
Gillis
1239 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12350
M
K


JK
Rowling
1240 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12351
F
2


Suzanne
Collins
1241 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12352
F
3


Tom
Segura
1242 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12353
M
4


Mitt
Romney
1243 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12354
M
6


Joe
Biden
1244 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12355
M
K


Chappel
Roan
1245 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12356
F
2


Jennifer
Lopez
1246 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12357
F
3


Kristen
Bell
1247 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12358
F
4


Barrack
Obama
1248 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12359
M
6


Michael
Jordan
1249 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12360
M
K


George
Ezra
1250 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12361
M
2


Micahel
Jackson
1251 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12362
M
3


Simon
Barjonah
1252 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12363
M
4


John
Mark
1253 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12364
M
6


Kristen
Wig
1254 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12365
F
K


Joe
Shmoe
1255 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12366
M
2


Katy
Perry
1256 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12367
F
3


Lady
Gaga
1257 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12368
F
4


Olivia
Rodgrigo
1258 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12369
F
6


Hayley
Williams
1259 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12370
F
K


Jimmy
Haffa
1260 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12371
M
2


Poki
Mane
1261 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12372
F
3


QT
Cinderella
1262 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12373
F
4


John
Deere
1263 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12374
M
6


Lily
Pichu
1264 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12375
F
K


John
Smith
1265 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12376
M
2


George
Washington
1266 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12377
M
3


Mia
Goth
1267 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12378
F
4


Denzel
Washington
1268 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12379
M
6


George
Bush
1269 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12380
M
K


Jennifer
Lawrence
1270 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12381
F
2


Taylor
Swift
1271 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12382
F
3


Kamala
Harris
1272 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12383
F
4


Nancy
Polosi
1273 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12384
F
6


Sjourney
Weaver
1274 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12385
F
K


Jennifer
Aniston
1275 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12386
F
2


Chloe
Moretz
1276 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12387
F
3


Betty
White
1277 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12388
F
K


Abraham
Lincoln
1278 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12389
M
6


Aubrey
Hepburn
1279 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12390
F
3


Teddy
Roosevelt
1280 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12391
M
2


Julia
Roberts
1281 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12392
F
K


Sydney
Sweeney
1282 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12393
F
4


Franklin
Roosevelt
1283 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12394
M
3


James
Madison
1284 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12395
M
2


Emily
Osment
1285 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12396
F
K


Corella
Deville
1286 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12397
F
6


Malifi
Cent
1287 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12398
F
6


John
Adams
1288 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12399
M
3


Alexander
Hamilton
1289 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12400
M
2


Baba
Yaga
1290 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12401
F
4


Bloody
Mary
1291 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12402
F
K


Morse
Code
1292 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12403
F
4


Thomas
Jefferson
1293 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12404
M
K


Aunt
Jemima
1294 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12405
F
6


Will
Turner
1295 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12406
M
3


Mother
Theresa
1296 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12407
F
2


Amelia
Airheart
1297 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12408
F
4


Davy
Jones
1298 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12409
M
1


Elizabeth
Schuyler
1299 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12410
F
3


Jack
Sparrow
1300 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12411
M
2


King
Charles
1301 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12412
M
1


Peggy
Schuyler
1302 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12413
F
3


Mark
Twain
1303 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12414
M
5


Huckleberry
Fin
1304 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12415
M
4


Angelica
Schuyler
1305 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12416
F
3


Atticus
Finch
1306 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12417
M
2


Mike
Meyers
1307 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12418
M
1


Lady
Washington
1308 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12419
F
3


Jack
Skelington
1309 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12420
M
4


Hermione
Granger
1310 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12421
F
5


Luna
Lovegood
1311 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12422
F
2


Emma
Watson
1312 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12423
F
3


Count
Dooku
1313 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12424
M
4


General
Grievious
1314 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12425
M
1


Darth
Sidious
1315 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12426
M
5


Meryl
Streepe
1316 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12427
F
3


Anakin
Skywalker
1317 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12428
M
2


Anne
Hathaway
1318 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12429
F
4


Christian
Bale
1319 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12430
M
1


Cole
Sprouse
1320 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12431
M
5


Zoe
Deschanel
1321 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12432
F
3


Brock
Lesner
1322 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12433
M
2


Mike
Tyson
1323 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12434
M
1


Rachel
Deschanel
1324 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12435
F
2


Nostra
Damus
1325 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12436
M
3


Caitlin
Clarke
1326 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12437
F
4


Serena
Williams
1327 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12438
F
1


Selena
Williams
1328 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12439
F
3


Judge
Judy
1329 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12440
F
2


Harriet
Tubman
1330 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12441
F
1


Janet
Austen
1331 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12442
F
1


Ginny
Weasely
1332 Internet Street
Internet
EE
12443
F
5



Here is sheet 2:



Blue
Red
Brown
Camo
Gray
Green

Yellow
Pink
Polka-Dot
Stripes
Orange
Purple




TL:
TL:
TL:
TL:
TL:
TL:

TL:
TL:
TL:
TL:
TL:
TL:


TA:
TA:
TA:
TA:
TA:
TA:

TA:
TA:
TA:
TA:
TA:
TA:


 1. Shane Gillis - K
 1. George Ezra - 2
 1. Tucker Carlson - 3
 1. Tom Segura - 4
 1. Mark Twain - 5
 1. Mitt Romney - 6

 1. Michelle Obama - K
 1. Mikaila Peterson - 2
 1. Suzanne Collins - 3
 1. Candace Owens - 4
 1. Lady Washington - 3
 1. Janet Parshell - 6


 2. Joe Biden - K
 2. Joe Shmoe - 2
 2. Micahel Jackson - 3
 2. Simon Barjonah - 4
 2. Darth Sidious - 5
 2. Barrack Obama - 6

 2. Kristen Wig - K
 2. JK Rowling - 2
 2. Jennifer Lopez - 3
 2. Kristen Bell - 4
 2. Hermione Granger - 5
 2. Olivia Rodgrigo - 6


 3. Michael Jordan - K
 3. Jimmy Haffa - 2
 3. George Washington - 3
 3. Huckleberry Fin - 4
 3. Cole Sprouse - 5
 3. John Mark - 6

 3. Hayley Williams - K
 3. Chappel Roan - 2
 3. Katy Perry - 3
 3. Lady Gaga - 4
 3. Emma Watson - 3
 3. Nancy Polosi - 6


 4. George Bush - K
 4. John Smith - 2
 4. Franklin Roosevelt - 3
 4. Jack Skelington - 4

 4. John Deere - 6

 4. Lily Pichu - K
 4. Jennifer Lawrence - 2
 4. Poki Mane - 3
 4. QT Cinderella - 4
 4. Meryl Streepe - 3
 4. Corella Deville - 6


 5. Thomas  Jefferson - K
 5. Teddy Roosevelt - 2
 5. John Adams - 3
 5. Count Dooku - 4

 5. Denzel Washington - 6
 5. Sjourney Weaver - K
 5. Jennifer Aniston - 2
 5. Taylor Swift - 3
 5. Mia Goth - 4
 5. Anne Hathaway - 4
 5. Malifi Cent - 6



 6. Davy Jones - 1
 6. James Madison - 2
 6. Will Turner - 3


 6. Abraham Lincoln - 6
 6. Betty White - K
 6. Mother Theresa - 2
 6. Chloe Moretz - 3
 6. Kamala Harris - 4
 6. Zoe Deschanel - 3
 6. Aunt Jemima - 6



 7. King Charles - 1
 7. Alexander Hamilton - 2
 7. Brock Lesner - 2




 7. Julia Roberts - K
 7. Luna Lovegood - 2
 7. Aubrey Hepburn - 3
 7. Sydney Sweeney - 4




 8. Mike Meyers - 1
 8. Jack Sparrow - 2
 8. Mike Tyson - 1




 8. Emily Osment - K
 8. Rachel Deschanel - 2
 8. Elizabeth Schuyler - 3
 8. Baba Yaga - 4




 9. General Grievious - 1
 9. Atticus Finch - 2
 9. Nostra Damus - 3




 9. Bloody Mary - K

 9. Peggy Schuyler - 3
 9. Morse Code - 4




 10. Christian Bale - 1
 10. Anakin Skywalker - 2






 10. Angelica Schuyler - 3
 10. Amelia Airheart - 4






I can get teams of 10, but sometimes a 1st grader will end up in a 5th grade team and other anomalies like that occur.

Consider a database solution to handle this problem in a relational model using a tabular set instead of iteratively with loops through Excel cells. Doing so, you avoid long-winded VBA code since all work is handled in readable and maintainable SQL logic.
If using Excel for Windows, consider MS Access (which ships with MS Office Professional). If using Excel for MacOS, consider SQLite3, the open-source, file-database counterpart where its Command Line Interface tool comes available via Homebrew.

Import Excel sheet into MS Access and importantly add an autonumber ID. For SQLite, save Excel sheet as CSV and then import the text file using the SQLite command line shell.
CampMembers


Create and save the following SQL queries to generate a grade-level sequence number; generate multipliers of sequence number to assign every 7, 8, 9, 10 students to teams based on human judgement; assign team sequence then transpose to wide format per second sheet. Note the query names where each query is used in subsequent query.
(In SQLite, use the ROW_NUMBER window function instead of subqueries and place all SELECT statements in a single query using Common Table Expressions, sadly not supported in MS Access.)
CampMembersSeqQ (Sequentially assign by grade using autonumber ID; since data contained only five 5th graders, they were lumped with 6th graders)
SELECT c.ID, c.[First Name], c.[Last name], c.Gender, IIF(c.Grade = 5, 6, c.Grade) AS Grade, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM CampMembers sub
        WHERE IIF(sub.Grade = 5, 6, sub.Grade) = IIF(c.Grade = 5, 6, c.Grade) 
          AND sub.ID <= c.ID
       ) AS SeqCount
FROM CampMembers AS c
ORDER BY IIF(c.Grade = 5, 6, c.Grade), c.ID;

CampMembersMultiQ (After review of above, below assigns multiples of 8, 9, 10, and 11 using integer division of sequence number by grade levels)
(In SQLite, replace IIF with CASE and INT with CAST.)
SELECT q.*, p.Grade AS OrigGrade, 
      INT(q.SeqCount / IIF(q.Grade IN (0, 3), 8,
                           IIF(q.Grade IN (4, 6), 9, 
                               IIF(q.Grade = 2, 11, 10)
                           )
                       )
      ) + 1 AS Teams
FROM CampMembersSeqQ AS q
INNER JOIN CampMembers AS p ON q.ID = p.ID
ORDER BY q.Grade, q.ID;

CampMembersTeamsQ (Assigns students by team sequence in prep for final query)
SELECT t.*, 
     (SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM  CampMembersMultiQ sub
      WHERE sub.Grade = t.Grade
        AND sub.SeqCount <= t.SeqCount 
        AND sub.Teams = t.Teams
     ) AS TeamSeq
FROM CampMembersMultiQ AS t;

CampMembersTeamsWideQ (Transform long data to wide format; in this example, at least 7 students were assigned to a team in same grade except last team)
(In SQLite, TRANSFORM is not supported. Consider conditional aggregation to transform long to wide.)
TRANSFORM MAX(t.[First Name] & ' ' & t.[Last Name] & ' - ' & t.OrigGrade) AS CampMember
SELECT t.TeamSeq
FROM CampMembersTeamsQ AS t
GROUP BY t.TeamSeq
PIVOT (t.Grade & '-' & t.Teams) IN ('0-1', '0-2', '1-1', '2-1', '2-2', '3-1', '3-2', '3-3', '4-1', '4-2', '6-1', '6-2');





Export last Access query to Excel. Rename columns ('0-1', '0-2', '1-1', etc.) to color-coded team names. For SQLite, use the command line tool to export query to csv format and then import CSV into Excel.

